# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context.intent.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)'

Tags: android, react-native

```
public void callInstamojoPay(String email, String phone, String amount, String purpose, String buyername) {
    final Activity activity = this;
    InstamojoPay instamojoPay = new InstamojoPay();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ai.devsupport.instamojo");
    registerReceiver(instamojoPay, filter);
    JSONObject pay = new JSONObject();
    try {
        pay.put("email", email);
        pay.put("phone", phone);
        pay.put("purpose", purpose);
        pay.put("amount", amount);
        pay.put("name", buyername);
        pay.put("send_sms", true);
        pay.put("send_email", true);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
    initListener();

    instamojoPay.start(activity, pay, listener);

}

InstapayListener listener;


public void initListener() {
    listener = new InstapayListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int code, String reason) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };
}
```

### -----------------------------

---

Attempt to invoke virtual method 
I am getting [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkJqy_ZKU_iHQY8ey2grRxwHjEdJZtzR/view?usp=sharing). 
Please help me to resolve the issue. 
I am new to react native and I don't have knowledge on android

Comment: What error?  Edit your question, something is missing here.

Comment: Please click the error Link

Answer (score 0):

> Try using this code it may help

```
private void callInstamojoPay(String email, String phone, String amount, String purpose, String buyername) {
    final Activity activity = this;
    InstamojoPay instamojoPay = new InstamojoPay();


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ai.devsupport.instamojo");
    Instamojo.initialize(YourActivity.this);



    registerReceiver(instamojoPay, filter);
    JSONObject pay = new JSONObject();
    try {
        pay.put("email", email);
        pay.put("phone", phone);
        pay.put("purpose", purpose);
        pay.put("amount", amount);
        pay.put("name", buyername);
        pay.put("webhook",BuildConfig.WEBHOOK_URL);
        pay.put("send_sms", true);
        pay.put("send_email", true);
        pay.put("description",purpose);

        Log.e(TAG, "callInstamojoPay: "+pay );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initListener();

    instamojoPay.start(activity, pay, listener);
}
```

> Call init initListener() inside onCreate()

Comment: @SharshaD make sure activity reference should not be null

Comment: I am not aware of that code. I don't know android and I can only implement partial react native.

Comment: Ok, but for me, it is working fine.I want to clarify that you are using this code in Activity or Fragment

Comment: I am creating the object 
//MainActivity ma =new MainActivity();
       //ma.callInstamojoPay("mail@gmail.com", "9999999999", "10", "test", "Vasu");

Comment: Don't create like this, do like  Activity activity=MainActivity.this. Pass this activity here : instamojoPay.start(activity, pay, listener);